# Table join using outer and inner in 1 statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to get all years for product and country pairs, which has at least 1 overlapping year. Is there any way to do it more efficiently than the query below?

```
CREATE TABLE#t1(product varchar(5), country varchar(5),time int)
CREATE TABLE#t2(product varchar(5), country varchar(5),time int)

INSERT INTO#t1 values ('water','uk',1), ('water','uk',2),       ('ice','uk',1)
INSERT INTO#t2 values ('water','uk',2),                         ('ice','uk',2)

SELECT *
FROM #t1 t1
         FULL OUTER JOIN #t2 t2 ON t2.product = t1.product
                                   AND t2.time = t1.time
                                   AND t2.country = t1.country

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ISNULL(t1.product, t2.product) AS product, 
           ISNULL(t1.country, t2.country) AS country, 
           ISNULL(t1.time, t2.time) AS time
    FROM #t1 t1
         FULL OUTER JOIN #t2 t2 ON t2.product = t1.product
                                   AND t2.time = t1.time
                                   AND t2.country = t1.country
) allMarkets
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           t1.product, 
           t2.country
    FROM #t1 t1
         INNER JOIN #t2 t2 ON t2.product = t1.product
                              AND t2.time = t1.time
                              AND t2.country = t1.country
) overlaps ON overlaps.product = allMarkets.product
              AND overlaps.country = allMarkets.country;

DROP TABLE #t1
DROP TABLE #t2
```

Comment: where are years stored?

Comment: It's time column

Comment: using the data in your example, what should be the desired result?

Comment: I don't unsdertand this values. http://rextester.com/QYJFB66876

Comment: The last query is desired result. It's taking too long, though.